# Rendering jtable cell foreground based on positive or negative values

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I'm not sure how I should approach this, what I want to do is have these P&L cells foreground be green when the value is greater than 0 and red if less than 0. I know I need to use tablecellrenderer somehow I'm just not sure how to start.

[image]

This is the table settings:

```
tbl_positions = new WebTable(posdata, posHeaders)
    {
        public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                int rowIndex, int vColIndex) {
            Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex,
                    vColIndex);
            if (rowIndex % 2 == 0 && !isCellSelected(rowIndex, vColIndex)) 
            {
                c.setBackground((new Color(216, 216, 216)));
            } 
            else 
            {
                if(!isCellSelected(rowIndex, vColIndex))
                {
                    if(rowIndex != 21)
                        c.setBackground(getBackground());
                    else
                        c.setBackground((new Color(216, 249, 255)));
                }
                else
                {
                    c.setBackground((new Color(0, 128, 255)));
                }
            }

            if(vColIndex == 5 || vColIndex == 6 )
            {
                Integer intValue = (Integer) getValueAt(rowIndex, vColIndex);
                c.setForeground(getColor(intValue));
            } 
            else 
            {
                c.setForeground(getForeground());
            }

            return c;
        }

        private Color getColor(Integer intValue) 
        {
            Color color = null;
            if (intValue > 0) {
                color = Color.GREEN;
            } else if (intValue < 0) {
                color = Color.RED;
            } else {
                color = getForeground();
            }
            return color;
        }
    };
```

It's now working:

[image]

Comment: See [Using custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). The easy way is by extending `DefaultTableCellRenderer` class and override `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For something as simple as setting the foreground, you don't *need* a custom renderer. You can simply override `prepareRenderer` of the `JTable`. Something like

```
JTable table = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
            int row, int col) {

        Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
        if (col == PL_COLUMN) {
            Integer intValue = (Integer) getValueAt(row, col);
            c.setForeground(getColor(intValue));
        } else {
            c.setForeground(getForeground());
        }
        return c;
    }

    private Color getColor(int intValue) {
        Color color = null;
        if (intValue > 0) {
            color = Color.GREEN;
        } else if (intValue < 0) {
            color = Color.RED;
        } else {
            color = getForeground();
        }
        return color;
    }
};
```

Take some time to go over [How to Use Tables: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) for more information on custom rendering

---

### UPDATE: full demo

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class TestTableRenderer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                NikeSaysJustDoIt();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void NikeSaysJustDoIt() {
        Random random = new Random();
        Object[][] data = new Object[30][7];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++)  {
                data[i][j] = (random.nextInt(65536) - 32768);
            }   
        }
        String[] cols = new String[] { "col", "col", "col", "col", "col", "col", "col" };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                    int row, int col) {

                Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
                if (col == 5 || col == 6) {
                    Integer intValue = (Integer) getValueAt(row, col);
                    c.setForeground(getColor(intValue));
                } else {
                    c.setForeground(getForeground());
                }
                return c;
            }

            private Color getColor(int intValue) {
                Color color = null;
                if (intValue > 0) {
                    color = Color.GREEN;
                } else if (intValue < 0) {
                    color = Color.RED;
                } else {
                    color = getForeground();
                }
                return color;
            }
        };
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));
    }
}
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE 2: Using all double values and a NumberFormat for the last row.

I left a bunch of comments that will help you to understand the code. Note that you may want to have to formatters. The image you have displays to different formats. One with currency sign and one without. Also some of your values are integers and some are decimals. So you will most likely need two formatters to get it the way you want.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TableFormatRenderDemo {

    public TableFormatRenderDemo() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(createTable()));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /*
     * We are using all double values. We leave the rendering to 
     * the renderer. The NumberFormat is used to format the text.
     */
    private JTable createTable() {
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
                { "AUD", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                { "CAD", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.00, -0.35 },
                { "CHF", 0.897, -1, 0.896, 0.0, -120.00, 0.00 },
                { "CHK", 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 },
                { "Total", null, null, null, null, 20125.00, 0.00 } };
        String[] cols = { "col 1", "col 2", "col 3", "col 4", "col 5", "col 6",
                "col 7" };
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, cols);
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return getPreferredSize();
            }
        };
        // Set the custom renerer
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new NumberFormatRenderer());
        return table;
    }

    private NumberFormat getFormatter() {
        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) formatter)
                .getDecimalFormatSymbols();
        decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("$");
        ((DecimalFormat) formatter)
                .setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);
        return formatter;
    }

    /**
     * Custom renderer we use for the table
     */
    private class NumberFormatRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 5152961981995932787L;
        private static final int PL_USD_COL = 5;
        private static final int DAILY_PL_COL = 6;
        // TODO We may want to have a setter for this formatter
        private final NumberFormat formatter = getFormatter();

        private final Color POSITIVE_COLOR = new Color(65, 185, 62);
        private final Color NEGATIVE_COLOR = Color.RED;
        private final Color LAST_ROW_COLOR = Color.CYAN;
        private final Color ALT_ROW_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
                Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                    hasFocus, row, column);

            renderAlternateBackground(row, table.getBackground(), table.getRowCount());
            renderForeground(row, column, table.getForeground(),
                    table.getRowCount(), value);

            // Formats the last row with the given NumberFormat
            if (row == table.getRowCount() - 1 && column != 0 && value != null) {
                setText(formatter.format((Double) value));
            }

            // Centers the text
            setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);

            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Renders the foreground. Render only if column is one of 
         * the predefined "PL" columns, using the helper method
         * <code>getColor</code> to determine the color to render based on the 
         * <code>value</code>.
         *  
         * @param row
         * @param col
         * @param tableForeground
         * @param rowCount
         * @param value
         */
        private void renderForeground(int row, int col, Color tableForeground,
                int rowCount, Object value) {
            if (col == PL_USD_COL || col == DAILY_PL_COL) {
                setForeground(getColor((Double) value, tableForeground));
            } else {
                setForeground(tableForeground);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Helper method for the <code>renderForeground</code> method. Returns
         * a <code>Color</code> base on the value.
         * @param value
         * @param tableForeground
         * @return
         */
        private Color getColor(double value, Color tableForeground) {
            Color color = null;
            if (value > 0) {
                color = POSITIVE_COLOR;
            } else if (value < 0) {
                color = NEGATIVE_COLOR;
            } else {
                color = tableForeground;
            }
            return color;
        }

        /**
         * Rendered alternate background color. Check for odd rows numbers.
         * The last row is rendered as the select <code>LAST_ROW_COLOR</code> color.
         * @param row
         * @param tableBackground
         * @param rowCount
         */
        private void renderAlternateBackground(int row, Color tableBackground,
                int rowCount) {
            if (row % 2 != 0) {
                setBackground(ALT_ROW_COLOR);
            } else if (row == (rowCount - 1)) {
                setBackground(LAST_ROW_COLOR);
            } else {
                setBackground(tableBackground);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TableFormatRenderDemo();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer if we're returning a color why do we cast it to an integer? @peeskillet

Comment: And why are we storing integer values as Strings? Your second question `getColor` is just a helper method I created so it's clearer to read. We need to cast to Integer because `getValueAt` returns Object, unless you overrode `getColumnClass` to return String for column

Comment: I added how my table is initialized, please take a look above @peeskillet

Comment: See my **UPDATE**. You're doing a whole lot of unnecessary stuff in your code. Most of that is done by the default renderer you obtain from doing `super.prepareRenderer`

Comment: As for the ClassCastException, you need to make sure the data you are storing are actually integers and not strings, or that you're not overriding `getColumnClass` and returning String.class

Comment: Or doubles. And cast to double instead, since you data are floating points

Comment: Also your last row might be a problem. Numeric values don't come with `$`. You probably are using Strings. In which case you may have to do some parsing. You can't to greater than/less than operations on Strings

Comment: The data is formatted in a using the getcurrencyInstance, like this:

NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols decimalFormatSymbols = ((DecimalFormat) formatter).getDecimalFormatSymbols();
    decimalFormatSymbols.setCurrencySymbol("");
    ((DecimalFormat) formatter).setDecimalFormatSymbols(decimalFormatSymbols);

but the variable is a double, but when I assign it to the array it goes through the format, does that change it to a string?
posdata[r][5] =formatter.format(openPL).trim();
posdata[r][6] = formatter.format(dailyPL).trim();@peeskillet

Comment: Yea the last row with the total is the problem I'm pretty sure because it returns a string, how would you parse this though in the cellrender @peeskillet

Comment: Don't save the data as Strings! Use a custom renderer to display the numeric data in whatever representation you want

Comment: If its just the last row that is formatted to String, then you can add that row to the column check `&& row != lastRow`

Comment: I don't think it's just your last row though, because you also have `20,000`. That's not a numberic value. Your best bet it to save everything as numeric data, then use a custom renderer where you format the way you want

Comment: not yet, see my issue that first column are string values but the rest of the table are doubles, but I can't set the array that stores these values to a double because of that first column. @peeskillet

Comment: That's why you use `Object` type. As long as you save the value as double value, it will automatically get saved as a double, then you can cast. But I would look into using a custom renderer. Seems you have a lot more going on than just change the foreground. It's late here. When I get a change tomorrow, I will work on a solution. Shouldn't be too difficult. In the mean time, try to work on it yourself. Save everything as number values (Object[][]). In the renderer you can use the formatter.

Comment: Yea it's a little bit of a complicated setup because there's a lot of formatting done and all the values are strings. Ok I'll give it a shot with the object[][], I leave work in 30 anyways I'll see what I can do till then. Thanks for all your help so far and sorry for all these questions I'm new to java @peeskillet

Comment: Got it to work with some adjustments, thank you so much for taking all this time to help me out with it really appreciate it! Check out the screenshot up top @peeskillet

Answer (score 0):

```
final class RenderRedGreen extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

          RenderRedGreen () {
            setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);   
          }

          @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue, boolean aIsSelected, 
            boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn) {  

            Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
              aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
            );
            if (aNumberValue != null && (Double)aNumberValue < 10) { //Checking if  cell´s values isnt null and the condition is true
                renderer.setForeground(Color.RED);
         }else{
             renderer.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
          }
            return renderer;
          }
        } 
    //Where you are retrieving data from database
        TableName.getColumnModel().getColumn(TableColumnName).setCellRenderer(new RenderRedGreen() );
```